# How to register an AsyncEventingBasicConsumer in F#

Tags: f#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to create an asyncEventBasicConsumer in F#. 
In order to do that I need to use `add_Received` that has the follow signature

```
member add_Received: 
   value: AsyncEventHandler<BasicDeliverEventArgs> 
       -> unit
```

But I don't have idea how to create an AsyncEventHandler from
 `async  {}`

This is the concrete function

```ml
let subscribe : Subscribe =
    fun factory queueName handleMessage ->
        let connection = factory.CreateConnection()
        let model = connection.CreateModel()
        let consumer = AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(model)
        consumer.add_Received //?? how create a AsyncEventHandler
        model.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer) |> ignore
        (fun () ->
        model.Close()
        connection.Close())
```

And here the c# code

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
    const string queueName = "myqueue";

    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);

        // consumer

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += Consumer_Received;
        channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

        // publisher

        var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        int i = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Message {++i}");
            channel.BasicPublish("", queueName, props, messageBody);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}

private static async Task Consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs @event)
{
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(@event.Body);

    Console.WriteLine($"Begin processing {message}");

    await Task.Delay(250);

    Console.WriteLine($"End processing {message}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
consumer.add_Received(fun sender event -> Consumer_Received sender event |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task)
```

Notable points are casting `async` to `Task` and upcasting `Task<'a>` to `Task`.